# link image with anchor function in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I already tried with

```
 <?php anchor('company/ourpartners',img(array('src'=>'/Images/OurPartnersLink.png','border'=>'0','alt'=>'testing image')),array('class'=>'imglink')); ?>
```

but this throws following error

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function img() in
>   /home/xxxx/public_html/application/views/homepage/index.php on line
>   160

any ideas?

Comment: Did u add this line in controller :$this->load->helper('html');

Comment: I thought it's clear from my question title, I want to link image using ci url helper

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`anchor` and `img` are in two different helpers. Have you included the [`html` helper](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/html_helper.html)?